# Dynamically get DB logical name when restoring from .bak file

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-2.7, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a python script that will dynamically restore databases from .bak files. Running the query

```
RESTORE DATABASE db_name FROM DISK = '\\path\to\db\db_name.bak' WITH REPLACE
```

works great if the original database name doesn't exist, however since there is multiple servers and often duplicate names this is not always the case.

In the case that the .mdf name contained in the .bak file does exist, the WITH MOVE syntax is useful as shown below

```
RESTORE DATABASE db_name 
  FROM DISK = '\\path\to\db\db_name.bak'
  WITH 
    MOVE 'Logical_name' TO '\\somepath\...\MyDB.mdf'
```

Unfortunately, this requires knowledge of the logical name before the query is run and is therefore not very useful for a general purpose script. Is there any way to get the logical name and populate it dynamically to make this more general purpose?

Comment: As far as I know bak is a proprietary format and there is no way to know how to parse it.

Comment: You might be able to utilize restore headeronly to retrieve details about what is contained in the backup set. Then adjust your script based on the contents you find. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx

Comment: Try to use :   DECLARE @BackUpPath nvarchar(2000)='D:\BackUpYourBackUpFile.bak'
EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY  FROM DISK=''' +@BackUpPath+ '''  ')  to get logical file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `restore filelistonly` commamd

Comment: I use this all the time. When I'm restoring by hand, I run this, copy/paste the logical and physical names into my query window, and then manipulate them into `move` clauses for the `restore` command.